# How import pmd ruleset in sonarQube 4.3.1

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

We have a number of rules implemented in a PMD ruleset. What do I need to do to import those in SonarQube? I could not find any option to import a ruleset.

Is the PMD plugin required to import PMD rules?

Many thanks,

Jaco Verheul

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot import an exesting ruleset. To make a custom PMD ruleset in SonaQube you have to install [PMD plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PMD+Plugin) at first. Then you can create you own [Quality profile](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) in SonaQube and enable the rules you want to use. All the PMD rules is in the PMD repository after you install the PMD plugin correctly.